# How to bundle the resources from an INSTALLED_APPS in Django with Webpack?

Tags: django, webpack

I have a main Django app, say myApp, which has subApp in its INSTALLED_APPS list. I use Webpack 5 to compile my main application's resources. The subApp is actually used in several applications which are in Django 2 and Django 3.

However I cannot find a way to tell Webpack, from myApp, to go look into subApp to compile the resource files that are in there. How could one do that? If it helps imagination, let's pretend there is no js/css optimisation in subApp and Webpack would manage that from myApp on compilation.

And if it's not possible directly in Webpack's config, would there be a way to import subApp's scripts and stylesheets in myApp's script files and stylesheets to make webpack compile them from there?

Any help welcome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader of any help?

Comment: Not really I fear, because it still needs the base_dir to the current app, and the issue is that I don't know how to set an entrypoint as something in INSTALLED_APPS. I think I'm really wondering "where are INSTALLED_APPS with regard to my actual project?" I feel that webpack-loader is more of a tool like manifest-loader, which (overly simplifed) resolves initial resources filenames to their compiled versions for html files.